# How to set the password for keytool in windows?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, keytool

I am adding google-maps-api for the my hellomapview progam for android appilication developement refering the website *[http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html][1]*.Before generating the api key it ask for md5-signature certificate.So when try to create md5 certificate using keytool via commandline in windows i got the following error.Please guide to this clear this error or how to set password and what is the default password for keytool.

Error:

*C:\Documents and Settings\USER>keytool -list -keystore .android\debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
incorrect*

Output with image:
http://bit.ly/gOrcfG

Comment: Thanks Guys for reply.I got the solution before few minutes ago.I referred this website.      http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-mapview-generate-api-key-using-java-keytool/            but now the map is not working in the android simulator.what kind of simulator i should use for this.

Answer (score 3):

you are not giving pass. for it. so try below:

---

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this windows batch command but I prefer to use an ant script: cleaner and simpler.

Here is the ant commands to use to generate a key:

```
    <genkey alias="${Alias}" storepass="${Password}" keystore="${KeyStore}" validity="${ValidityDays}">
      <dname>
        <param name="CN" value="Antoine PINEAU" />
        <param name="OU" value="AP2cu" />
        <param name="O" value="ap2cu.com" />
        <param name="C" value="FR" />
      </dname>
    </genkey>
```

Here are the ant commands to use to signa jar with the generated key:

```
    <signjar jar="${JarFile}" alias="${Alias}" storepass="${Password}" keystore="${KeyStore}" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much.I solved that error just before few minutes ago,I referred to the website and i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try not pass any password. I had the same problem, but I got the error when I give a passwork. (After all, I never configured a password for keystore before).

When I just press enter with no password, my fingerprint was created.